# Flutter Create Command was Unsuccessful in Android Studio IDE?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk

I want to Create a new Flutter Project. A Project is already created and working/running fine, but when I attempt to create a new project, I get the following message:

```
Flutter Create Command was Unsuccessful
```

Why would this message appear and how can I create a new Flutter Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you completely close the current project. You can create a new flutter project from the command line using

```
flutter create
```

Then just open the project

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe" "D:\path\to\flutter_project"
```

Comment: Hi, i opened a project and then set the Flutter new project and Flutter sdk path , Now project created successfully, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of this problem , here i just configure the Flutter SDK path
and now create command is working.